# Error: NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays Angular 13

Tags: angular, blob

NgFor works with arrays, and my server is sending Objects,Its clear. But With the following function present in service file,when I make the `response-type:Blob`

```
API_SERVER = 'http://localhost:3000';

public getallbooks(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpclient.get(`${this.API_SERVER}/books`, {
      observe: 'response',
      responseType: 'blob',
    });
```

**I'm getting the following error.**

`ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

I tried by removing `<any>`,and make it `<Book>`,but then I get new errors.I have to make `response-type Blob` because I'm receiving images as **text/html**.And according to some **stackoverflow answers**, we need to convert the response as blob to get the images.

**Angular GET request for data from server**

```
 BookForm = new FormGroup({
    _id: new FormControl(''),
    name: new FormControl(''),
    author: new FormControl(''),
    price: new FormControl(''),
    genres_name: new FormControl(''),
    coverimage: new FormControl(''),
  });
  results?: Book[];
  sub = new Subject();

  constructor(
    private readonly apiService: ApiService,
    private router: Router,
  ) {}

 ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService.getallbooks().subscribe((data: Book[]) => {
  this.results = data;
  for (const i in data) {
    this.BookForm.value.coverimage = data[i].coverimage;
  }
  console.log(this.results);
  this.sub.next(this.BookForm.value.coverimage);
  this.createImageFromBlob(this.BookForm.value.coverimage);
  return this.sub.asObservable();
});
  }
createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener(
      'load',
      () => {
        this.image = reader.result;
      },
      false
    );
    if (image) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([this.image]));
    }
  }
```

**ngFor in html**

```
<div class="grid" *ngFor="let result of results">
      <div class="blog-card spring-fever" style="padding: 0.5rem; z-index: 100">
        <div *ngIf="result.coverimage">
          <img
            class="image"
            src="http://localhost:3000/{{ result.coverimage }}"
            alt=""
            height="400px"
            width="250px"
            style="border: 1px solid red"
          />
        </div>
<div class="title-content">
          <h3>
            <a href="#">{{ result?.name }}</a>
          </h3>
          <div class="intro">
            <h5>
              <a>Author<b>:</b>&nbsp;{{ result?.author }}</a>
            </h5>
```

**Backend response when `response-type` is not set to `blob`. And the product is visible but the Network shows images are with `text/html`  with 200 status**
[image]

**Backend response when `response-type:blob`.**

[image]

**DevTool Network Response with both `src="http://localhost:3000/{{ result.coverimage }}"` and `src="http://localhost:3000/assets/{{ result.coverimage }}"`**

[image]

**DevTool Network Response with `src="{{ result.coverimage }}"`**

**console. With this it's seeking images at `localhost:4200` that is surprising, because all the images are present in servers's `assets` folder,and server runs on `localhost:3000`**
[image]
**Network**
[image]

Comment: can you post an example of the actual response you are getting back from the backend?

Comment: Why your `responseType` is blob for `getAllBooks()`?

Comment: @Andres2142
I've added the Backend response. You can view at the end of my question.

Comment: @Rana_S
I am able to  show other data of my products(Books) at frontend, but the images are in `text/html`. So after searching I found that I have to make the response type of the images `Blob`. Although those solutions are not for those images that are attached with some other product and the referenced is saved in database. But I thought give it a try It might work. I have an `index.html` in server's assets folder,all the images goes after upload.Without `index.html` my NestJs server throws an error and demands for an index.html file. Without `index` my images response is `JSON with 404`

Comment: You have list of books and each book has path for its image. I see that you already have `ngFor` and set the image src with the path. Any issue with that?

Comment: @Rana_S
Yes you are right. I have no issue with what you said. The only issue is that after so many tries and searching I'm not able to display the books with images. So it would be a great help if you/someone solves the issue.

Comment: @Andres2142
?@Rana_S? You didn't reply...

Comment: I think, based on your screen shot for the data, the image src is incorrect. Check the network/console from dev tools. If you are loading from server, give a correct path.

Comment: I've add some screen shots that shows `network/console from dev tools` information. Please observe them. And if I didn't understand your last comment correctly about `img src`,then please explain a little bit more about what you were trying to explain me.

Comment: As seen on the network tab, the paths are incorrect and you get 404 (marked res). Click on one of the network calls and check the url whether it matches your actual url. If not, correct them.

Comment: @Rana_S
I added two different screen shots yesterday at the end of my question.But I think you only saw the last screen shot.I get `404` with `src={{result.coverimage}}`,but with `src="http://localhost:3000/{{result.coverimage}}"`, I get images with `200` status and type is `text/html`.When I hit `http://localhost:3000/ImageNameInServer.png`, the image is visible in google. The url is correct.The url matches with the actual url.If somehow you have missed the screen shots then please see all the screenshots again.

Comment: I am referring to the latter ones where you have 404 with `/assets/…` If you just take the url and enter in your, does it work. I am not getting what you trying to solve? Aren’t you trying to solve the issue displaying the images?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to display the images. But why it will display the image if I'll put `localhost:4200/assets/image.png` in the browser?.It's obvious that I'll get a `Get 404` error,because the images are not at that url,there is no such folder at `4200`.All the uploaded images from Angular goes to the NestJs assests folder,and this assets folder is present at `3000` port.With `src={{result.coverimage}}`, Angular is trying to get the images from `4200` port,that is illogical because  all the data is coming from `3000` port.

Comment: Ok I think you are trying to say that if data is at 3000,and it's giving error about 4200,then change the url from 4200 to 3000.Well I don't know how to do that.I never saw someone before doing this in any Angular project. And you can see at the top of my question in my service file,I already have set the url with 3000 port.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are struggling to display the images coming from server, like I was, or you are struggling with the data that is coming from a server specially NodeJs and NestJs. SO I wouldn't recommend to convert your response to `responseType:blob` or something else. Because to display the data coming from server we need a `ngFor` loop, and when we set our reponse to blob, that means our data is no more present in an array form. And it has become Objects or list of Objects, you can say. And in Javascript Objects are not iterable.So the error `ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`, is not something related to server or Angular, it is due to our logic that is we trying to implement, that is out of the JavaScript's rule boundary.**

And If somebody does not understand the meaning of `Iterable`, like I also didn't know some time ago, It means **Something that can be loop over. or things that can be repeated**.

**So in my case** I had a  list of books and each book has path for its image. I was using `ngFor` and set the image `src` with the path. That is the right way. But the images were not visible and Network was showing images as `text/html` type. The actual issue here was not the `type`, but I was searching and trying to convert that response `text/html` to image format by making `responseType:blob` in my service file. But then I found that the actual issue was in my `URL`.I had a folder in NestJs server by the name of `assets`,that is preset at `root`, and I had set the path for the images(in NestJs file upload code), like this `./assets/`. That is also the correct way to set the destination folder.I was able to see the images at browser like this `http://localhost:3000/imagename.png`,and that means my server configured to server/serve my images over root URL that's why I  can access them `http://localhost:3000/imagename.png`. But my api was returning images in a format that contains `./assets/` in the URL. So with the following code

```
<div *ngIf="result.coverimage">
          <img
            class="image"
            src="http://localhost:3000/{{ result.coverimage }}"
            alt=""
            height="400px"
            width="250px"
            style="border: 1px solid red"
          />
        </div>
```

I am assuming that I'm hitting the Url like this  `http:localhost:3000/imagename.png`. But actually Angular was seeing the URL like this `http:localhost:3000/./assets/imagename.png`. And **this is note the correct URL Format**. Urls don't work with `.` or `,`.Also becasue my server is configured at root, this url`http;//localhost:3000/assets/imagename.png` is also wrong.And `root` means that, whatever the thing is set at `root`, that is directly access able after your server's port number. Example `http://localhost:YourServerPortNumber/TheThing_Set_at_Root`.

> **So the solution for this issue is the following**

```
src="http://localhost:3000/{{
              result.coverimage.replace('./assets/', '')
            }}"
```

With above `.replace('./assets/', '')` we are removing the `./assets/` and repalcing it with `''` empty space. So now URL is in this format`http://localhost:3000/imagename.png`.

**Also now I don't need the `createImageFromBlob()` function and the `for in loop` or other array mothode to extract all the images from subscribed data,and simply you can write your code like this to display the data**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService.getallbooks().subscribe((data: Book[]) => {
      this.results = data;
      console.log(this.results);
  });
  }
```

**I hope I understood the things myself correctly and explained them correctly**